# Scale up and scale down cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an ECS service that I want to scale up and down depending on how many items are in an SQS queue.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "sqs_scale_up" {
  alarm_name = "scale-up"

  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "1"
  metric_name               = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
  namespace                 = "AWS/SQS"
  period                    = "60"
  threshold                 = "1"
  statistic                 = "Sum"
  alarm_description         = "Increase task count"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
  alarm_actions             = [aws_appautoscaling_policy.scale_up.arn]

  dimensions = {
    QueueName = aws_sqs_queue.this.name
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "sqs_scale_down" {
  alarm_name          = "scale-down"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "ExactNumberOfMessagesVisible"
  namespace           = "AWS/SQS"
  period              = "60"
  threshold           = "1"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  alarm_description   = "Decrease task count"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_appautoscaling_policy.scale_down.arn]

  dimensions = {
    QueueName = aws_sqs_queue.this.name
  }
}
```

The fact that I have 1 alarm for `count>0` and 1 alarm for `count<1` means that one of these alarms will be be in the alarm state?

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't panic over the word '**ALARM**'. Instead, think of it as saying that the condition is **TRUE**.

If there are *any* messages in the queue, you presumably want to **scale-out** from a "nothing is running" state. Therefore, you want the scale-out alarm to be TRUE. However, you need to **set a limit so that it doesn't continually scale** -- it might just need one pod.

When the queue is empty, you want to **scale-in**. However, you don't want to flip-flop between the two states. The general rule is *"**scale-out quickly, but scale-in slowly**"*. Therefore, the rule should use a longer evaluation period before deciding to scale-in (eg 10 minutes).

Thus, there might not always be an alarm in the TRUE (ALARM) state. If there are no messages in the queue, then the scale-out alarm will be FALSE. Plus, if the sum of `ExactNumberOfMessagesVisible` over the previous 10 minutes is not zero, then the scale-in alarm won't be TRUE either. Instead, **both alarms will be FALSE** so nothing will be changing at that time. This is good.

Answer (score 0):

Such settings `count>=1` and `count<1` looks little bit odd, but it depends on what you want to achieve.
It might be ok if you need scale-down ECS to 0 in case if you don't have message to process and provision some resources otherwise.

There are caveats associated with such approach, in the worst case when messages come, processing will be delayed for 60 sec + ECS provisioning time.

From other hand, if you want to have ongoing message processing and always have some bare minimum of workers on duty processing messages, but you need to scale up, try to adjust `threshold` value accordingly to values that is greater than average amount of messages in queue + some threshold.